# How to get a paypal access token using REST request

Tags: rest, paypal, jersey-client

I'm trying to get this working https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/
Using Java + Jersey application. It seems like I'm missing something in POST params.

```
public String getPaypalToken() {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    queryParams.add("username", CLIENT_ID + ":" + SECRET );
    queryParams.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").acceptLanguage("en_US").type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(ClientResponse.class, queryParams);
    return response.toString();
}
```

Using previous code I got: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized.

This CURL command line option just works fine:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token  -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Accept-Language: en_US"  -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp"  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
J.

Answer (score 1):

The -u option in curl sends a base64 encoded "username:password" string. I don't think adding client id / secret to the queryParams map does the same (unless Jersey treats the 'username' key differently which I don't think it does).

You should instead try

webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(CLIENT_ID + ":" + SECRET.getBytes()))

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing my solution:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");

string clientid = "<your client id>";
string secretid = "<your secret id>";
string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientid, secretid, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
```

I previously encountered unauthorized response using RestSharp, then found this. I'm using paypal .net sdk from nuget package.
[Reference.](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/dotnet?env=sandbox)

Comment: can you tell how to get in android?

Comment: try this [article](https://techtrendzy.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/get-an-access-token-for-rest-api/) or [example from paypal](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/java?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) you will need PayPal Java Rest SDK for the second link, not exactly Android example but it's in Java... haven't worked yet in Android, if you teach me Android maybe we can solve your problem faster :))